# How to fetch Friend list from facebook in iOS 9 fb sdk 4.8 or above?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-friends

I am using way mentioned below to find friend list but it is not working. And earlier methods i used (FBRequestConnection) is not working any more may be they are not supported any more. Please guide.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields": @"name"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                 [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     // TODO: handle results or error of request.
                     NSLog(@"request friend list:%@", request);
                 }];
```

Respsonse i got from this is:

```
request friend list:<FBSDKGraphRequest: 0x7fc77af33bc0, graphPath: /me/friendlists, HTTPMethod: GET, parameters: {
"access_token" = CAAIDdxjgZCZAQBAIupnz8fToFBh4YzgdvTAVciQZAZBj1kX8h7iZCYc1WSqVBVmmiCKRuAbymzRVcQeLZAIhhssc6JkB50rsOFJK6KwsuEiK6B1jvPuaUNZAIm2YqlZCg1INs9ZCoyqOo6lmRjjkttxX2RrkWZAUEDxE8lP9DApbyDh5ZChbsPT5zZAsdRMj3tQkVxLXyLaMXxN9rbPxU8lZCs57HbhOQXmkZD;
fields = name;
format = json;
"include_headers" = false;
sdk = ios;
}>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting --- NSError *error?? log it

Comment: not getting the error Please check the question again i  posted the update there.

Comment: Dude! you are printing the request, not the response. Be active! Log the "result" and "error"

Comment: Ya man just got gone through Graph API explorer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But also missing one thing need to pass the permission for "user_friends" at the time of login.

Answer (score 0):

First of all need to pass the permission parameter "user_friends" at the time of login.Then use the below code to get list.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields": @"name"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                 [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     // TODO: handle results or error of request.
                     NSLog(@"request friend list:%@", result);
                 }];
```